# Out of memory while encoding to Base64

Tags: android, base64

I am dividing a file into chunks and each chunk is encoded into Base64. But I am getting OutOfMemory error on `encodeToString`. My code is as follows:

```
try {
      in = new FileInputStream(zipEntity.zip_file);
      long bytesLeft = in.available();

      long chunkOffset = 0;

      int i = 0;
      while (bytesLeft > 0) {
      i++;
      // TODO: what happens if int MAX_VALUE exceeded?
      long maxChunkSize = chunkSizeBytes > 0 ? chunkSizeBytes : bytesLeft;

      byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) Math.min(bytesLeft, maxChunkSize)];
      int read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

      bytesLeft -= read;

      Log.e("", "===== " + i + ", BYTES LEFT === " + bytesLeft);

      boolean isLast = bytesLeft == 0;
      chunks.add(new FileChunkEntity(Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT), chunkOffset + "", isLast));

      i++;
      chunkOffset += buffer.length;
    }
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       if (in != null)
           try {
                 in.close();
               } catch (IOException ex) {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }
   }
```

I am getting error at this line:

```
chunks.add(new FileChunkEntity(Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT), chunkOffset + "", isLast));
```

I have tried the same with `Base64OutputStream`, but String obtained from `Base64.encodeToString` is not matching with `outputStream.toString`.

When I tried `outputStream.toByteArray)`, I didn't got out of memory error but `new String(outputStream.toByteArray)` didn't matched with `Base64.encodeToString()`

Comment: the memory is not infinite. you probably need to unload your chunks from the memory after you processed them

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I am storing them in linkedlist. During processing, I am calling `linkedlist.poll()` as it removes the head from the linkedlist. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I don't see how you do that in this part of code